# How to display forum on a custom URL on my site?

Tags: 7, nodes

The default URL of forum is `./forum` but I want it to move to `./discuss/forum`
How can i accomplish same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), [url alias](http://drupal.org/node/120631) to  your forums to achieve the same.  if it is a custom menu you can use hook_menu_alter(). or an .htaccess re-direct if it is a permanent change

Comment: I have used pathauto but breadcrum is still showing 
Home >> forum
instead they should show:
Home >> discuss >> forum
Menu item discussions is also not highlighted

Comment: is discussions having a separate page or a menu item, unless it does have menu item will not be linked or highlighed?

Comment: No, forums are on default URL ./forum
I have custom menu item linked to ./forum